# Is it possible to create a Text Index on dynamic fields in Mongodb for text query search?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, full-text-search, eve

Is it possible to have dynamic text field creation on a text index without dropping the text index itself?

We have data coming into our Eve API layer that can have any `{key: value}` pair that we want to do a text search on (the key can be any string name). Right now we have it hardcoded for when we create the text indexes and on what fields, like so:

```
           app.data.driver.db['name_collection].create_index(
                [
                    ("first_name.text", pymongo.TEXT),
                    ("last_name.text", pymongo.TEXT),
                    
                ],
                name="text",
            )
```

This won't work once we introduce dynamic fields, however. Any thoughts?

Comment: What is a dynamic field and how does one create an index on an index?

Comment: I'm referring to the Text Indexes that support text search queries that are provided by MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: Okay, that didn't answer either question though.

Comment: A dynamic field is just a field that can be anything set by the user. See how first_name.text  and last_name.text are hardcoded? If the user decided he want to do text search on something else like the middle name, we have to account for the middle_name.text afterwards. We already indexed the first_name and last_name fields for text search, but not the middle_name.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#wildcard-text-indexes